# Updating parsed JSON data into GridView

Tags: android, json, parsing, gridview, android-asynctask

i'm trying to get data from mysql and display in GridView but i couldn't make it. it turns out errors. i hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Here is my AllIconsActivity.java code:

```
   public class AllIconsActivity extends Activity {

GridView gridView;
SimpleAdapter adapter;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> iconsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_icons = "http://192.168.1.130:8080/android_connect/get_all_icons.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_TB_MainContent = "TB_MainContent";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_ICONNAME = "iconname";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray TB_MainContent = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_icons);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    iconsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllIcons().execute();

  gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1); 

    // Get listview
  // ListView lv = getListView();
   // GridView lv = getGridView();
    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long pid) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditIconActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllIcons extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllIconsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading icons. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_icons, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Icons: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                TB_MainContent = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TB_MainContent);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < TB_MainContent.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = TB_MainContent.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String iconname = c.getString(TAG_ICONNAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_ICONNAME, iconname);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    iconsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewIconActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllIconsActivity.this, iconsList,
                        R.layout.screen_list, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_ICONNAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.iconname });
                // updating listview
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

Here is my activity_all_icon.xml code

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3" >


</GridView>
```

Here is my screen_list.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/iconname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="15px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my errors:

```
Activity com.example.digital_catalog.AllIconsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40524628 that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.digital_catalog.AllIconsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40524628 that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:266)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:174)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:117)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
at    com.example.digital_catalog.AllIconsActivity$LoadAllIcons.onPreExecute(AllIconsActivity.java:126)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
at com.example.digital_catalog.AllIconsActivity.onCreate(AllIconsActivity.java:63)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to it with by:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
// if result code 100
  if (resultCode == 100) {
    // if result code 100 is received
    // means user edited/deleted product
    // reload this screen again
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    startActivity(intent);
 }}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it doesn't help. Errors still appear.